# How get users permissions report to all site collections on SharePoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am looking for a solution on how I could generate a report with users permissions to all site collections on SharePoint Online using PowerShell.

Using the script below, I get all data about the sites. Is it possible to retrieve only the url value of each site as a response from this script?

```
Connect-SPOService -url "https://...-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credential (Get-credential)
Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL | Export-CSV -LiteralPath C:\Temp\SitesInventory.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Below is a fragment of the second script generating the report with users permissions to the specified site collection

```
...
$SiteURL = "..."
$ReportFile = "C:\Temp\UsersPermissionsReport.csv"
GeneratePnPSitePermissionsReport -SiteURL $SiteURL -ReportFile $ReportFile -Recursive
```

Using the second script generates a report with users permissions to the specified site collection but I would need to iterate on all sites returned from the first script and generate a report with users permissions for each of them

Answer (score 0):

this link is valid for a single site collection:

[link](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/09/sharepoint-online-site-collection-permission-report-using-powershell.html)

You can try to loop this in all site collections, like this below:

foreach ($SiteCollection in SPOSite) {do your stuff here}

Comment: Yes correct, I just used the materials on this page before, but thanks for the answer anyway.